# Handling clicks in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, prototypejs, prototype

I have the following setup:

Js prototype lib.

A span that has an onclick event that calls a function sort of the following:

```
function onClickSuperFunction() {
     alert('Super function called');
     // Bla bla bla many epic things
     if (someCondition) {
          $('selectorForSameSpan').click();
          // selectorForSameSpan is a selector for the element that was originally clicked (first click is manunal)
     }
}
```

In all browsers except IE, everything is ok. In IE the click is not fired (is fired when I manually click the element, but not the event from "if").

Also, if I change the selector and simulate a click on any other element ( $('anyOtherSpanForExample')), it works ok (the function is called).

So... does IE  prevent automatic clicks on the same element? Maybe an antispam something? And... any work-around? I really need that click.

Note: Same thing happens if I use the prototype "fire".

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrototypeJS by default doesn't support firing native browser events.

Add Event.simulate to your page and it will allow you to fire native events in all the browsers that PrototypeJS supports.

Integrating Event.simulate into the core is in the plans, in the meantime here is the Github gist

https://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/5b56fdafcd7d7662c9d648534225039b2e78e371/event.simulate.js

Comment: Ty, still... why doesn't native call work? And normally I would ask why only IE sucks but... I've asked myself that so many times already...

Comment: depending on the version of IE it might not have the `click()` method on the element, but listed in a cache of events. The simulate methods figure that out for you and fire it from the right place.

Comment: I know, is a good solution (hence the +1), but unfortunately I need approval for new libs and this usually takes ages. So until they approve of that I need to finish this native.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the code in Event.simulate and use it to fire the native event in IE.

Comment: That's actually a nice idea. And also the only decent one so I'll accept your answer.